# An error is reported when reading an empty s3 file through SparkContext.textFile and using the DataFrameWriter.insertinto method

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Read S3 file of txt format

```java
JavaRDD<String> textRdd = sparkContext.textFile(filePath, 3).toJavaRDD().repartition(60);
```

The filePath is like 's3a://bucket_name/object_name'. BTW, spark can't read s3 file by s3filePath like above when the bucket name contains underscore symbol, i.e. '_', I'm really confused about this.

Here omit transToRowRdd process, i.e., change JavaRDD< String > to JavaRDD< Row >.

---

The write process

```java
Dataset dataset = SparkSession.createDataFrame(rowRDD, fieldSchemas)

DataFrameWriter tableWriter = dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("hive");

tableWriter.insertInto(fullTableName);
```

---

If the s3 file is empty, an error will be reported in the insertinto method.

```
23/08/03 19:43:20 INFO Driver ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.SaveAsHiveFile.saveAsHiveFile(SaveAsHiveFile.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.SaveAsHiveFile.saveAsHiveFile$(SaveAsHiveFile.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.saveAsHiveFile(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.processInsert(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.run(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewQueryId(SQLExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:767)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:519)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:473)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:750)

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, , executor 4): java.lang.Exception: The requested range cannot be satisfied. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 416; Error Code: InvalidRange; Request ID: )
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:141)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1428)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The requested range cannot be satisfied. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 416; Error Code: InvalidRange; Request ID: ), S3 Extended Request ID:
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1073)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:721)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:456)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2752)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.openIfNeeded(S3AInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:156)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:392)
    ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2737)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2673)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1083)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2866)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2855)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:861)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
    ... 33 more

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: The requested range cannot be satisfied. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 416; Error Code: InvalidRange; Request ID: )
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:141)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1428)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The requested range cannot be satisfied. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 416; Error Code: InvalidRange; Request ID: ), S3 Extended Request ID:
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1073)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:721)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:456)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2752)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.openIfNeeded(S3AInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:156)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.fillBuffer(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:392)
    ... 16 more
)
```

---

When read an empty csv formatted s3 file, everything works fine.

```java
JavaRDD<Row> javaRDD = sparkSession.read().format("csv").option("enforceSchema", true).option("header", "true").load(filePath).javaRDD();
```

---

When I read a non-empty s3 file of any format, everything works fine.